# How to get timestamp value of only date

Tags: javascript, node.js, timestamp

I am new to Node Js
I am using **Date.now()** to get the timestamp of current time
But i wanted the timestamp value of only current date not including the time.
For Example
Now current time is  *August 9, 2017 8:19:28 PM* and the timestamp will be *1502309968000* 
But I want timestamp of only *August 9, 2017 12:00:00 AM* and the timestamp will be *1502236800000*
How to solve this ?

Comment: The question is confusing! Only date means only `August 9, 2017`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a date object, and set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to zero

```js
var date = new Date();

date.setHours(0,0,0,0);

var time = date.getTime();

console.log(time);
```

Note that [`setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) accepts minutes, seconds etc. as well.

`.setHours(hoursValue[, minutesValue[, secondsValue[, msValue]]])`

Answer (score 1):

just set the Hours to 0

```
d = new Date();
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try http://momentjs.com/ 
It will give you the format that you needed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOzwA.png)